# Mvc3 Html.Encode and MarkdownSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, markdownsharp, html.encode

I am using MarkdownSharp in an mvc3 project.
The user is able to insert text into a textbox, that might be dangerous, so that he can write something like "2 < 3".

So I am not able to block all dangerous inputs.

To display the text, I want to encode all the dangerous characters with

```
Html.Encode(myString)
```

but this also encodes new-line and so on, so that after that I cannot use MarkdownSharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(myString).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))
```